# Executing command on all opened buffers

Tags: variables, emacs, quote

I have opened lots of file in emacs using `C-x C-f /path/to/files/*.txt`
Also I have created and saved a keyboard macro named it as `my-macro`

Now I want to running this macro on all the opened buffers. How can I do this in emacs?

I would like to mentioned that I am new to emacs and also don't know about emacs lisp code but can code well in C++.
So If anyone who suggest or give some lisp code, please favour me by writing the comment also so that I can modified that so any needed.

**EDIT 1:**
I have tried by marking all the opened buffers by **m** and then **E** then `Eval(form): my-macro` 
But getting the below error

> Symbol's value as variable is void: my-macro

Comment: You only want to process file-visiting buffers, I presume?

Comment: @phils yes I have already opened the files. I think you mean this only.

Comment: No, I mean that not all buffers in Emacs are associated with files, so when you say "all the opened buffers" I think you actually mean *only* the buffers which are visiting files, and you should probably clarify that in your question. Or if you mean only files under the `/path/to/files/` directory, you should state that.

Comment: @phils yes you are correct! Sorry I didn't get your question last time, as I am not that much comfortable with emacs jargon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is giving you a clue: "Symbol's value as variable is void"

my-macro is not a variable containing a value.  You need to quote the macro like that: `'my-macro` (or the equivalent `(quote my-macro)`)

If you really want to execute the macro in all buffers (beware the buffers like `*Messages*` and so), this would be a programatic alternative

```
(defun execute-my-macro-in-all-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (if (and buffer-file-name
               (y-or-n-p (format "Execute macro in %s? " buffer-file-name)))
          (execute-kbd-macro 'my-macro)))))
```

Comment: Yes... but I am not getting the desired result because I need to have the cursor the beginning of the file. As the message say "operation completed on 21 buffers.

Comment: So start your macro with `M-<` to move to the beginning of the buffer?

Comment: @juanleon Do I need to run this in *scratch* buffer. Can you please make the above code much interactive, in much It ask If I want to run this on current buffer or not.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you want.

Comment: `(if (and buffer-file-name (y-or-n-p (format "Run my macro on %s" buffer-file-name))) ...` ?

Comment: Getting error "keyboard macros must be string or vector". I've tried using backtick and single quote charter before the macro name.

Comment: Strange, since it works for me.  What does "C-h f RET my-macro" yield?

Comment: macro-print-preety-memory-usage-data is an interactive Lisp function.

(macro-print-preety-memory-usage-data &optional ARG)

Keyboard macro.

Comment: Looks like my-macro is not a macro anymore.  Maybe you restarted your emacs session and did not saved the macro in your init file, maybe you redefined it with a function

Comment: No I have saved in init.el file. Which I can invoke on a single buffer as "M-x macro-print-preety-memory-usage-data"

Comment: Have you replaced "my-macro" by "macro-print-preety-memory-usage-data" in the above function?